# mysql query syntax error，LIMIT can't used before UNION any more after mysql8.0？

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL：

```
select * from t_google_receipt limit 1 union select * from t_old_google_receipt limit 1；
```

the sql in my code excuted sucessful in my old mysql(Server version:        5.6.17-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)),but after updated to mysqlGroup(Server version:        8.0.11 MySQL Community Server - GPL), it excuted failed,

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'union select * from t_old_google_receipt limit 1'
>   at line 1;

Comment: Limit without Order by makes no sense generally, as data is stored in unordered fashion. So rows (without order by) returned will be indeterministic

Comment: "To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT: " Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya 'no sense whatsoever' is slightly over-stating it. 'LIMIT 1' *can* be used to test if there is any result, but essentially I agree with the sentiment.

Comment: @Strawberry updated.

Comment: but why it can be excuted in old mysql version,the LIMIT used like this in the code written by someone before and can't run after upgrade mysql.

Answer (score 4):

It actually changed in [MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```
>
> Note
>
> Previous versions of MySQL may permit such statements without
>   parentheses. In MySQL 5.7, the requirement for parentheses is
>   enforced.

Beware anyway that if you don't provide individual `ORDER BY` clauses you'll get arbitrary rows (not even random).

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses:

```
(select * from t_google_receipt limit 1)
union
(select * from t_old_google_receipt limit 1)；
```

Notes:

- You probably want `union all` and not `union`.
- The use of `limit` without `order by` is suspicious.
- This assumes that the columns in the two tables are the same, defined in the same order, and have compatible types.

Answer (score 0):

For union and union all you have to consider below point

1. Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of
   columns
2. The columns must also have similar data types
3. The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

So in case of two tables union it is bad practice  to use select all(select *) column from table rather it is preferable and less error to use column name explicitly like below

```
 select col1,col2... coln from t1
 union 
 select col1,col2.....coln from t2
```